# Should I save gems right now?

Tags: brave-frontier

I'm a new Brave Frontier player, with a Global account. Right now I have about 10 rare units, no healers and no whites, and enough gem for 2 Rare summons.

Since there has recently been a "Super Rare units guaranteed" should I save until another one appears, or should I just summon asap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I waited, and in hindsight it was the right thing to do, seeing that yesterday there was a Super rare guaranteed.

It seems these things are fairly common in Global, unlike Europe where I have yet to see one.

Comment: Unless I'm very much mistaken, the version available in Europe IS the Global version. There's also a Japan-exclusive version which, as far as I know, is much further advanced than Global.

Comment: You are kind of mistaken, there is a "Europe" version known as "Brave Frontier RPG", available in Spain, italy and France (don't know about other counties) that is different from the Global, which is available in other European countries, as you said. I can state this for a fact since I have both a Global and a "Europe" account.

Comment: I have this game in U.S. and there are always some sort of event.